How to pass multi row value to with clause in spring boot data?
We have a query in our repository that has 2 in clause. One gets a list of ides, another gets about max of 10 values. In DB2 we get error code of 101 when we pass more than 8000 ids to first in clause. Another way is to edit query to use with clause with multi row value to join with table we use. But I can't pass the list of values to repositories method.
My query is like this:
WITH ID_TABLE (ID) AS (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),), ... ,(10000))
SELECT N.TERMINAL_ID         AS terminalId,
       N.TAG_NO              AS tagNo,
       N.VALUE               AS value
FROM NOTIFY N
         INNER JOIN ID_TABLE
                    ON N.TERMINAL_ID = ID_TABLE.ID
WHERE N.TAG_NO IN ('A', 'B', 'C')

My full repository method is like:
@Query("""
        WITH ID_TABLE (ID) AS (VALUES :values)
        SELECT 
            N.terminal_id   AS terminalId,                              
            N.tagNo         AS tagNo, 
            N.value,        AS value 
        FROM Notify N 
            INNER JOIN ID_TABLE
                ON N.TERMINAL_ID = ID_TABLE.ID
        WHERE N.tagNo IN (:tags) 
        """, 
        nativeQuery = true)
List<TerminalTag> find(@Param("values") List<Long> values, @Param("tags") List<String> tags); 

My question is how I pass values of (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),), ... ,(10000) to query?
I tried String, List<String>, List<Long> but didn't work!
thanks for your helping.

It didn't work, what did happen? Error, wrong query ? Stating that it didn't work is a bit unspecific.

If you check it in debug mode you will see that values not passing in way that I want so you will get error.
I don't know how to pass values to be like (1), (2), ... (10000)

Afaik variable substition only works in the where clause not else where in the queries.

So what is your suggestion?

I would make your service smarter, cut the list of values into a list of lists of x size (x the size that your db supports) and then issue individual queries for those parts. Combining the results afterwards. You could even execute those queries in parallel (if there are multiple).

I tested this way but it takes longer time to fetch with multiple request to DB with in clause with list of ids.
And I want to find a way to pass values like this not other query solutions.

Even when executed in parallel?

Yes I tested with parallel stream. It takes 40 seconds.
